# For odd prime $p$ the elementary symmetric polynomial $e_j(r_1,...,r_{p-1})\equiv 0$ mod p for $1\leq j <p-1 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For odd prime $p$ the elementary symmetric polynomial $e_j(r_1,...,r_{p-1})\equiv 0$ mod p for $1\leq j <n$ where $r_i$ are the elements of the reduced residue class mod p

Definition is the same as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) so I assume this is a standard definition.

I tried a few examples for prime $3,5,7$ and I can see a bit of what is happening.

For example for $p=5$ we get $e_3=1\cdot 2 \cdot 3+1\cdot 2\cdot 4+1\cdot 3 \cdot 4+2\cdot 3 \cdot 4=1+(-2)+(-(-2))+(-1)=0$ mod 5

I'm unsure of how to prove this, I think maybe it uses the fact that modulo $p$ is a field and so when multiplying the elements of the reduced residue class you get sum of all the elements in the field which is $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ be a non-multiple of $p$. Notice that 
$$a^j e_j(r_1,\ldots,r_{p-1})=e_j(ar_1,\ldots,ar_{p-1})
\equiv e_j(r_1,\ldots r_{p-1})\pmod p$$
since (i) $e_j$ is homogeneous of degree $j$ and (ii) the $ar_i$ modulo $p$
are a permutation of the $r_i$ and $e_j$ is a symmetric function.

If $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, then $a^j\not\equiv1\pmod p$
as $0<j<p-1$. Therefore
$$e_j(r_1,\ldots,r_{p-1})\equiv 0\pmod p.$$

(You don't really need primitive roots: all you need is the fact that
$a^j\equiv1\pmod p$ has $\le j$ solutions in $\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$).